# MS Access fso.copyfolder hanging up during procedure

Tags: vba, ms-access

I set up an event to run in Access whenever the user presses a certain button.  part of the event includes copying files.  In this particular instance, the script gets hung up each time during this procedure:

```
set fso = createobject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
fso.copyfolder "S:\oldfolder", "S:\newfolder"
set fso = nothing
```

S:\oldfolder has ~1200 subfolders and successfully copies ~270 subfolders before throwing the error message, "Path not found".  If I press debug and comment it out, then it continues just fine with the other folders copying, moving, deleting.

I've tried using fso.movefolder as well as name "c:\oldfolder" as "c:\newfolder", but I get the same results.

When I manually copy/paste the folders, everything copies fine with no errors (but of course takes a bit longer).

this is on a shared network drive, and I've also tried running the scripts after hours and on the weekend when I know nobody else has any of the files open.

the only thing I can think of is that there may be some hidden files (like thumbs.db) that are not able to be copied/moved?

If it is the thumbs.db, how can I exclude that file from being included in the copy procedure?

thanks!

changing the script; running after hours, checking permissions, making sure nobody else has any of the files/folders in use

Comment: I was able to re-produce the error message by removing a folder while `fso.copyfolder "S:\oldfolder", "S:\newfolder"` was running. I do not know if you have the same issue but this could be a reason.

Comment: Could there be a path\file in there that is longer than 260 characters?

Comment: not sure, but certainly possible. is there a quick way for me to find out?

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that a folder was removed while `fso.copyfolder "S:\oldfolder", "S:\newfolder"` was running. You do not need to have the same problem but one could use the following code to circumvent this.

```
Sub testFso()

    Dim fso As Object
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    On Error GoTo EH
    fso.copyfolder "S:\oldfolder", "S:\newfolder"

    Exit Sub

EH:
    ' basic information which is shown in the debug box as well
    Debug.Print Err.Description, Err.Number
    ' Other code resp. more checking like
    If Err.Number = 76 Then
        MsgBox "One folder seems to be missing", vbOKOnly
        Resume
    Else
        MsgBox "Other Eror, no resume", vbOKOnly
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, I'll give that a try. although, it's highly unlikely that a folder was moved during the process, as nobody else was online when I ran it.